# Same output of the Keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, classification

I have a Keras model for predicting moves in the game. I have an input shape of `(160,120 ,1)`. I have the following model with an output of 9 nodes:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import optimizers
def alexnet_model(n_classes=9, l2_reg=0.,
    weights=None):

    # Initialize model
    alexnet = Sequential()
    alexnet.add(Conv2D(24, (11, 11), input_shape=(160,120,1), activation ='relu'))
    alexnet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    alexnet.add(BatchNormalization())
    alexnet.add(Conv2D(36, (5, 5), activation ='relu'))
    alexnet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    alexnet.add(Conv2D(48, (3, 3),  activation ='relu'))
    alexnet.add(Conv2D(54, (3, 3),  activation ='relu'))
    alexnet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    alexnet.add(Flatten())
    alexnet.add(Dense(300,   activation ='tanh'))
    alexnet.add(Dropout(0.5))
    alexnet.add(Dense(200,   activation ='tanh'))
    alexnet.add(Dropout(0.5))
    alexnet.add(Dense(100,   activation ='tanh'))
    alexnet.add(Dropout(0.5))


    alexnet.add(Dense(n_classes , activation = 'softmax'))

    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)

    alexnet.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)


    alexnet.summary()


    return alexnet
```

Then, I run a training script. My `X` has a shape of `(12862, 160, 120, 1)` and `y` of `(1000,9)`.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers,models
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
# what to start at
START_NUMBER = 60

# what to end at
hm_data = 111

# use a previous model to begin?
START_FRESH = False
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 1

MODEL_NAME = 'model_new.h5'
EXISTING_MODEL_NAME = ''

model = alexnet_model()

X=[]

Y=[]
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    train_data = np.load('training_data_1.npy')
    print(len(train_data))
    train = train_data[0:12862]
    test = train_data[-1000:]

    X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
    Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])

    test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
    test_y = np.array([i[1] for i in test])
    print(X.shape)
    model.fit(X, Y , batch_size = 16, epochs = 10 , validation_data = (test_x, test_y), verbose=1)
    model.save(MODEL_NAME)

# tensorboard --logdir=foo:C:/Users/H/Desktop/ai-gaming-phase5/log
```

After testing the model I get an output:

```
array([[2.8518048e-01, 5.5075828e-03, 7.3730588e-02, 5.3255934e-02,
        1.0635615e-01, 6.4690344e-02, 9.1519929e-08, 7.0413840e-08,
        4.1127869e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

with this line of code:

```
model.predict(X[100].reshape(-1,160,120,1))
```

I know that it is not good to test model on `X` but it doesn't matter which picture I use but I get the same output. Just for reference (my `Y` values):

```
w = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
s = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
a = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
d = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
wa = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
wd = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
sa = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
sd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
nk = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

I tried another model but it still doesn't work. Here is the amount of training data for each class:

```
Counter({'[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]': 5000,
         '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]': 5000,
         '[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]': 1183,
         '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]': 982,
         '[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]': 832,
         '[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]': 764,
         '[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]': 101})
```

I think that the problem is in the model but I don't know how to change it. Could it be the problem of small training data? The loss valus is also not going down: `loss: 1.7416 - val_loss: 1.4639`. It only decreases by a few decimals and sometimes even goes back up.

Comment: "y of (1000, 160,120,1)"?? You are performing 9-class classification. So `y` must have a shape of `(n_samples, 9)`?!! Further, tell us more about the training result: does the loss value decreases during training? what about the accuracy?

Comment: Also, could you load your training data outside of the epoch loop, process it into X, Y, test_x, test_y and print the shape of each of them? Use `epochs=10` as an argument to `model.fit` to train for more than one epoch, rather than calling `model.fit` multiple times.

Comment: In general debugging these issues is not easy, specially through Stack Overflow. If the loss does not decrease, then that is your problem, and you should not test a model that did not converge. Such information is missing here.

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: @KyrKalash The input data is images, right?

Comment: Yes. It is an image

Answer (score 1):

From what it appears in your code, and since you mentioned that the loss is decreasing very slowly, the best guess is that the input data (which I think are images) is not normalized and therefore this prevents a smooth gradient flow. Try normalizing them. One simple way of doing it is like this:

```
X = X.astype('float32') / 255.0
test_x = test_x.astype('float32') / 255.0
```

Further, you may need to account for the class imbalance in the training data and counter it by using `class_weights` argument in [`fit`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) method (look at the doc to find out how it can be used).

Comment: Division by 255 doesn't help  as well as class_weights

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Just normalizing training data didn't work. I decreased amount of nodes and layers and everything worked fine. I guess it was an overfitting problem.