# Loss not decrasing and is very high keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm learning deep learning in keras and I have a problem.
The loss isn't decreasing and it's very high, about 650.

I'm working on MNIST dataset from `tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist`
There is no error, just my NN isn't learning.

There is my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import tensorflow.nn as tfnn

inputdim = 28 * 28

model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(inputdim, activation = tfnn.relu))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = tfnn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = tfnn.softmax))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 4)
```

and my output:

````
Epoch 1/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 32s 527us/sample - loss: 646.0926 - acc: 6.6667e-05
Epoch 2/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 39s 652us/sample - loss: 646.1003 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - l - ETA: 0s - loss: 646.0983 - acc: 0.0000e
Epoch 3/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 35s 590us/sample - loss: 646.1003 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 544us/sample - loss: 646.1003 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```
````

Comment: You can try change your optimizer and add more epochs to your train. Make some tests with that. Try using Sigmoid activation in your NN.

Comment: Not sure about dataset, do you normalize the images? And loss is so big, try to set batch size.

Comment: You probably have not normalized the images. If that's the case then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52859705/2099607) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53987162/2099607).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I added `BatchNormalization` between lines and changed loss function to `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`. That's how my NN looks like:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1, momentum = 0.99))
model.add(Dense(inputdim, activation = tfnn.relu))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1, momentum = 0.99))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = tfnn.relu))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = 1, momentum = 0.99))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = tfnn.softmax))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

and thats a results:

```
Epoch 1/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 68s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.2045 - acc: 0.9374
Epoch 2/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 55s 916us/sample - loss: 0.1007 - acc: 0.9689
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good job in figuring out the issues; you should *accept* your own answer - please see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You may try sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss function. Also what is your batch size? and as has already been suggested you may want to increase number of epochs.